# Arranging letters

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Using the letters $A,C,E,F,I,H,O,P,S,$ and $T$ (with no repetition),how many $4$ unique  letter grouping can be created that:

a) Start with $A,C,E$ **or** end with $C,E,S,T$ ?

my approach is: $3$ choices for the first letter then 4 choices for the last letter,now i have used only $2$ letters, so we are left with 8 letters.

$(3)(8)(7)(4)= 672$

However, it does not match the answer that I have.Most likely the word "**or**" causing me a problem

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for displaying numbers and functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Use inclusion/exclusion principle:**

---

Include the number of combinations starting with A,C,E:

$$\binom{3}{1}\cdot\binom{10-1}{4-1}\cdot(4-1)!=1512$$

---

Include the number of combinations ending with C,E,S,T:

$$\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{10-1}{4-1}\cdot(4-1)!=2016$$

---

Exclude the number of combinations starting with A and ending with C,E,S,T:

$$\binom{1}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{10-2}{4-2}\cdot(4-2)!=224$$

---

Exclude the number of combinations starting with C and ending with E,S,T:

$$\binom{1}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{1}\cdot\binom{10-2}{4-2}\cdot(4-2)!=168$$

---

Exclude the number of combinations starting with E and ending with C,S,T:

$$\binom{1}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{1}\cdot\binom{10-2}{4-2}\cdot(4-2)!=168$$

---

**Hence the answer is $1512+2016-224-168-168=2968$.**

Comment: You set up the problem correctly.  However, $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{10 - 2}{4 - 2} \cdot (4 - 2)! = 1 \cdot 4 \cdot \frac{8 \cdot 7}{2 \cdot 1} \cdot 2 = 224$$ while $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{10 - 2}{4 - 2} \cdot (4 - 2)! = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{8 \cdot 7}{2 \cdot 1} \cdot 2 = 168$$  You should obtain $2968$ rather than $2912$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Oops, probably a copy-paste mistake... Thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the keyword in this problem is the "or." We can solve this problem using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

First, we count the groupings that start with A, C, or E. We have $3$ choices for the first letter, $9$ for the second, $8$ for the third, and $7$ for the last.

Next, we count the groupings that end with C, E, S, or T. We have $4$ choices for the last letter, $9$ for the first, $8$ for the second, and $7$ for the third.

Now we address the overcount - some cases have been counted twice above. We use casework here, as A and C are available both first and last.

**Case 1:** C or E first, C or E last

We pick either C or E to be first, and the other will go last. This totals $2 \cdot 8 \cdot 7.$

**Case 2:** C or E first, S or T last

We pick either C or E to be first, and either S or T to be last. This totals $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 7.$

**Case 3:** A first, C or E last

This gives $2 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$ more ways.

**Case 4:** A first, S or T last

This gives an additional $2 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$ ways.

The total overcount is $560.$

Our final answer is $9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot (4 + 3) - 560 = \boxed{2968}.$

Comment: This is not quite right because it counts cases where C and E are both first and last.

Comment: I accounted for those now.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Arrangements that begin with A, C, or E:

We can choose the first letter in three ways.  Since we can use each letter at most once, this leaves us with nine choices for the second letter, eight choices for the third letter, and seven choices for the fourth letter.  Hence, the number of arrangements that begin with A, C, or E is 
$$3 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 1512$$

Arrangements that end with C, E, S, or T:

We can choose the last letter in four letter ways, the first letter in nine ways, the second letter in eight ways, and the third letter in seven ways.

$$4 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 2016$$

However, we have counted those arrangements in which the first letter is A, C, or E and the last letter is C, E, S, or T twice.  We must subtract those arrangements so that we only count them once.

Arrangements that begin with A and end with C, E, S, or T:

We have one choice for the first letter, four choices for the last letter, eight choices for the second letter, and seven choices for the third letter.  Thus, there are 
$$1 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 4 = 224$$
such arrangements.

Arrangements that begin with C and end with E, S, or T:

We have one choice for the first letter, three choices for the last letter, eight choices for the second letter, and seven choices for the third letter.  Thus, there are 
$$1 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 3 = 168$$
such arrangements.

Arrangements that begin with E and end with C, S, or T:

This is the same as the preceding case except that the roles of C and E are interchanged.  Hence, there are also $168$ such arrangements.

Thus, the number of arrangements of four letters chosen from A, C, E, F, H, I, O, P, S, and T in which the first letter is A, C, or E or the last letter is C, E, S, or T is $$1512 + 2016 - 224 - 2 \cdot 168 = 2968$$

**Method 2:**

We determined above that there are $1512$ arrangements that begin with A, C, or E.  We add to them the number of arrangements that end with C, E, S, or T that do not begin with A, C, or E.

Arrangements that end with C that do not begin with A or E:

There is one way to choose the last letter, seven ways to select the first letter (since we must exclude A, C, E), eight ways to select the second letter, and seven ways to select the third letter.  Thus, there are 
$$7 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 1 = 392$$
such arrangements.

Arrangements that end with E that do not begin with A or C:

This is the same as the previous case except that the roles of C and E are interchanged. Hence, there are also $392$ such arrangements.

Arrangements that end with S or T that do not begin with A, C, or E:

There are two choices for the last letter, six choices for the first letter (since we must exclude the last letter, A, C, and E), eight choices for the second letter, and seven choices for the third letter.  Thus, there are 
$$6 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 2 = 672$$
such arrangements.

Hence, there are 
$$1512 + 2 \cdot 392 + 672 = 2968$$
arrangements in which A, C, or E is the first letter or C, E, S, or T is the last letter.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First, your suspicion that **or** is a problem is correct.  You have tried to require that the first letter be A, C, or E with your $3$ **and** that the last letter be C, E, S, or T.  You only need one of them to be true.  Your second problem is that the two selections are not independent.  If you choose E for the first letter you don't have it available for the last, but that isn't a problem when you get the **or** right.

What you need is the number of ways to get either the first or last to match the requirement.  You have three ways to get the first.  If that is true, you have nine choices for the next, eight for the next, and seven for the last. If you don't get the first, you need to separate the two cases here you get S or T, when you will only have three choices for the last letter, from the other five where you get four choices for the last letter.

Answer (score 0):

There are $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7$ possibilities without any restrictions,

so we can subtract the words that start with one of F, I, H, P, O, S, T and end with one of F, I, H, P, O, A.

1) If the word starts with one of F, I, H, P, O, then

$\;\;\;$there are 5 choices for the 1st letter and 5 choices for the last letter, so there are $5\cdot8\cdot7\cdot5$ words.

2) If the word starts with S or T, then

$\;\;\;$there are 2 choices for the 1st letter and 6 choices for the last letter, so there are $2\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6$ words.

Thus there are $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7-5\cdot8\cdot7\cdot5-2\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6=\color{blue}{2968}$ possible words.